# Vector intrinsic function not detected in vscode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, vectorization

I am using VS Code 1.75.1, C/C++ microsoft extension installed, and have `#include <immintrin.h>` at the top of my file. My architecture supports avx and avx2 (checked with `lscpu` and I am using Ubuntu 22.10).

Why am I getting the intellisense error below from VS Code? It suggests that `_mm256_fmadd_pd()` is undefined I think because the problem shows that the function takes no arguments and its return type is the default type of `int`.

Moreover, you can see that the VS Code hinted functions do not include `_mm256_fmadd_pd()` (even if I scrolled to the bottom of the hinted functions, it is still not there).

Note, I compile with `gcc -mavx2 -mfma -o minimal minimal.c` and no errors are thrown during compilation. However, if I just compile with the `-mavx2` only without the `-mfma` flag, the following error is thrown:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/include/immintrin.h:105,
                 from minimal.c:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/include/fmaintrin.h: In function ‘main’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/include/fmaintrin.h:47:1: error: inlining failed in call to ‘always_inline’ ‘_mm256_fmadd_pd’: target specific option mismatch
   47 | _mm256_fmadd_pd (__m256d __A, __m256d __B, __m256d __C)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
minimal.c:9:22: note: called from here
    9 |     __m256d result = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a, b, c);
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

AVX2 supports the fuse multiply-add operation (see [intel docs](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/intrinsics/intrinsics-for-avx2/intrinsics-for-fused-multiply-add-operations/mm-fmadd-pd-mm256-fmadd-pd.html)). I could also compile with `gcc -march=native -o minimal minimal.c` (I based this flag on [this](https://github.com/essentialsofparallelcomputing/Chapter6/blob/master/GlobalSumsVectorized/Makefile.simple) github makefile) and that leads to no compilation errors.

[image]

Comment: Please post all your code (forming a [mre]) and error messages, as copy-pasted text, not images. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors.

Comment: I have updated my question. The variables are uninitialized in this simple example, but in either case, vscode does not detect ```_mm256_fmadd_pd()```

Comment: So this is only in the intellisense, right? If you compile it it works?

Comment: Correct, it is only in intellisense.